# Grid item clickable not working

Tags: android, gridview

I have used one gridview calendar in my application.The gridview calendar is working correctly and displayed the element what i want.My problem is when i click the grid item this will not be clickable.Thanks

**> My Gridview:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="-1px"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:textDirection="anyRtl" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**> My Grid Rows:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gridcal"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/griddate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
    <!-- android:layout_height="200dp" -->
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridstatus"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

**> My Activity:**

```
gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewid);
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
           //some codes
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the OnItemClickListener interface in AdapterView, that is

> new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

Comment: i am not understanding

Comment: Do you have following code in your import statement like, 
import AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Comment: i am not using this...but now i am check it out your code in my adapter but not working